# Backbone.js - Search Field: use only one Item

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i'm using backbone.js and i want to limit the search field options to only one column, instead of all. I've found that the dropdown list, next to the search field, is located at the /assets/js/app/bbGrid.js at the function "_.extend(bbGrid.SearchView.prototype, Backbone.View.prototype"

specifically i'm trying to edit the following template code at the above function:

```
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">\
                    <% _.each(cols, function (col, index) {%>\
                        <li <% if (index === searchOptionIndex) { %>class="active"<% } %>>\
                            <a name="<%=index%>" href="#"><%=col.title%></a>\
                        </li>\
                    <%})%>\
                </ul>\
```

Instead of creating the multiple dropdown list of all columns, i want to remove the iteration and create only one '" href="#"><%cols[0].title%>\', instead of a multiple list of all the columns.

I'm completely noob with javascript and i cant find a way to print specific values (as i do in python or java) to find out the structure of "cols", or "function" that the above code iterates through "col" and "index" to assign the multiple search values.

I'll be grateful to any suggestion on how to eliminate the iteration and assign only one value, or how to understand the data type of the "cols" and "function". I mean are they dicts/lists or something else? If i know that i'll be able to google more specifically.

Thank you in advance for any help/advice :)

Comment: You should check the code where the particular View is created. You will find the _.template() method there. The data for the template is passed through this method. In this data you will find the 'cols' object. Can you post the code of the Backbone View?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Here's the relevant "template" code i found and actually the whole function's code:

http://pastebin.com/DkH90Eh4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found that the `index` was just a numerical (instead of objects inside array) iteration on the total objects of the `function`, the desirable snippet at the _extend function i mentioned above is:

`<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">\
                            <li>\
                                <a name="<%=0%>" href="#"><%=cols[0].title%></a>\
                                <a name="<%=1%>" href="#"><%=cols[1].title%></a>\
                            </li>\
                    </ul>\`

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume that cols is an array of object.

So when you do `_.each(cols, function (col, index) {...})` you are iterating through this array and for each element in it you will execute the callback `function (col, index) {...}` (function is not a variable it's like a java method) passing to it the this current element `col` and its position in the array (0, 1, 2 ... cols.length).

If you want to access the first element you can do `cols[0].title`

Comment: That's what i mentioned in my first post, that "cols[0].title" for some reason it doesn't work, also the "_.each(cols, function (col, index) {...})" is not my code, is part of the API from "Backbone.js".

And i don't know a way to identify if it's an array of objects. Is there an interpreter for javascript, like ipython for python? I would use the corresponding "print var" and "type(var)" for javascript if i had an interpreter. Tryied to do that testing inside Google Chrome's console but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: In Google Chrome's console you have to make a breakpoint at the line `cols[0].title`, in the console type cols and it will print the variable structure ([...] => it's an array, {...} => it's an object)

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain what happens in the code.

The [Underscore `template` method](http://underscorejs.org/#template) returns a function that allows you to instantiate that template. The HTML of the template is the first parameter of the method. Logic can be added here between the tags `<%` and `%>`.

```
template: _.template(
    '<div class="input-append">\
       <input name="search" class="span2" type="text" placeholder="<%=dict.search%>">\
       <div class="btn-group dropup">\
           <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">\
           <span name="column"><%=cols[0].title%></span>\
           <span class="caret"></span>\
           </button>\
           <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">\
               <% _.each(cols, function (col, index) {%>\
                   <li <% if (index === searchOptionIndex) { %>class="active"<% } %>>\
                       <a name="<%=index%>" href="#"><%=col.title%></a>\
                   </li>\
               <%})%>\
           </ul>\
       </div>\
   </div>', null, templateSettings
),
```

Now comes the part where you instantiate the template. You pass 3 models to the function: `dict`, `searchOptionIndex` and `cols`. This data will then become available in the template.

If you want to know the exact content of `cols` you should set a breakpoint at this line and check the contents of the object. Check your browser documentation on how to debug javascript.

```
searchBarHtml = this.template({
   dict: this.view.dict,
   searchOptionIndex: this.searchOptionIndex,
   cols: searchColList
});
```

When you look at the HTML of the template you will find them here aswell.
The [Underscore `each` method](http://underscorejs.org/#each) loops through all elements in an array passed as the first parameter. So we can assume `cols` is an array.In then executes the function passed as the second parameter for each element in the array.

```
<% _.each(cols, function (col, index) {%>\
    <li <% if (index === searchOptionIndex) { %>class="active"<% } %>>\
        <a name="<%=index%>" href="#"><%=col.title%></a>\
    </li>\
<%})%>\
```

I hope this clears some things for you. If you have any specific questions, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for you information! This is what i get from the brakepoints at the Chrome's log:

a) 'col.title' is a string (as i suspected)
b) 'cols' returns:

`[{"title":"ID","name":"h_id","index":true,"width":"33px"},{"title":"Email","name":"h_email","index":true},{"title":"Facebook Email","name":"h_facebook_email"}] `

c) 'cols[0].title' returns:

`ID` as string so col solved.

d) `<%= console.log(function)%>\` returns:
`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-js: "http://localhost/credentials/assets/js/app/bbGrid.js". `

How handle 'function'for 1 item?